# Last Active on Facebook without any mobile session

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-privacy

It's been a long since I removed all my Facebook App for Android. However I still can see "last seen" timestamp. How? I have two FB accounts, A and B.

A -> chat turned off, no app sessions in Secury except for the actual desktop session.

B -> incognito mode, chat on, can see A seen "1 min" ago and every time A use facebook.

As far as I know, this used to happen **only** with mobile apps.

Comment: More specifics about your platform and browser is needed.  Are A and B friends with each other?

Comment: Also keep in mind that most browser incognito modes, though they don't record new history and cache in incognito,are primarily to prevent storing local traces, not to prevent external web sites from correlating your sessions.

Comment: A and B are friends, yes. So I should better test running A on one machine, and B on another, and see what I get?

Comment: That would be a useful test. If you really want to reduce FB's ability to correlate your A and B accounts (aside from them being friends with each other) then you should take extra precautions: Always use separate machines, devices, or VMs, with separate IP addresses and device fingerprints. Log in at different times. Don't geo-tag images. Follow all of the general privacy recommendations in both accounts to protect *from* Facebook (including blocking Facebook trackers in apps and on the web). Even be mindful of your your language constructions, idioms, etc. that could be used to identify you.